# does dropping materialized view deletes all indexes and data used to speed up queries?

Tags: oracle, materialized-views

I created a materialized view which significantly sped up

> select * from table

query above. After, I dropped materialized view, this query is still returning records as fast as with materialized view.

I used `drop materialized view viewname` query to drop MV. Do I need to do anything else to return table to previous state ?

Comment: It seems unlikely that a materialized view would speed up a query against a physical table without a predicate.  In that case, the materialized view would simply make a copy of the table.  Unless that copy was on faster disk or the segment was substantially smaller for some reason (in which case you'd be better off shrinking the table segment), it should't be any faster to full scan the materialized view.  The fact that dropping it didn't affect query performance makes sense if the MV wasn't helping anything in the first place.

Comment: Seems more likely you just have the entire table in the buffer cache now.